# Why am I getting the "is not a registered namespace" error?

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-urls

My project was working fine before I added `get_absolute_url`, but after adding it, when I make a request to the main page, it gives the `get_absolute_url` error.

I don't know what parts of my project to write, but I will write possible things that I think will be useful

error:

```
    raise NoReverseMatch("%s is not a registered namespace" % key)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'blog' is not a registered namespace
```

templates:

Django says this is the problem

```
<a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}"><h4>{{ post.title }}</h4></a>
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post 


def detalis(request, title):

    post = get_object_or_404(Post, title=title)
    return render(request, 'blog/post-details.html', {'post': post})
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('post/<str:title>', views.detalis)
]
```

models.py:

```
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        print(reverse('blog:post', (), kwargs={'title': self.title}))
```

I hope this information is enough

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason. I was encountering the same error and adding `@staticmethod` decorator over `get_absolute_url()` stopped this error.